# Mongoose disconnects/reconnects every 30 seconds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We are using nodejs and mongoose on our production server. The mongo logfiles are full with connects/disconnects. They all happens every 30 seconds.

```
Wed Jan 15 10:08:52.280 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.3.138.16:50946 #1089677 (137 connections now open)
Wed Jan 15 10:09:22.291 [conn1089677] end connection 10.3.138.16:50946 (140 connections now open)
```

Does anyone have a clue about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [the fine manual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) states:

> A note about `keepAlive`
>
> For long running applictions it is often prudent to enable `keepAlive`.
>   Without it, after some period of time you may start to see `"connection
>   closed"` errors for what seems like no reason. If so, after reading
>   this, you may decide to enable `keepAlive`:

```
options.server.socketOptions = options.replset.socketOptions = { keepAlive: 1 }; 
mongoose.connect(uri, options);
```